# Why do classical laws fail at small scales?(Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, wave-particle-duality

So I came across a question in my textbook:

Explain why we can not apply classical laws to very small
scales, but we can to large scales:

a. using the de Broglie wavelength of matter.

b. using Heisenberg’s uncertainty principle.

For part a, I know we have to use the equation: $\lambda$ = $\frac{h}{p}$ , but what else would I need to include in my answer?

For part b, I am completely lost.

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to directly give you the answers, so here are some hints:

a) If you think about the de Broglie equation, it is saying that all matter has some wavelike properties. By applying classical laws, we typically ignore the wavelike properties of most matter (e.g. billiard balls, cars, humans). For large scales, what are typical de Broglie wavelengths? Why can we neglect the wavelike properties of things with those wavelengths?

b) What does the uncertainty principle say? It gives a lower limit to the joint uncertainties of two things. Typically, on large scales, we don't think there are any lower limits to uncertainty (e.g. I can know exactly where my billiard ball, car, or friend is and how fast it is / they are going). If you look closely at the uncertainty principle, you'll get a feel for why this lower limit to the joint uncertainty can be ignored at large scales.